# How do you add an item into an array if passes the logical statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to create a new array `B_array` based on an existing array A `A_array`.  If that item in `A_array` has a certain field then add it into `B_array`.

Currently this is what I have and its putting everything into `B_array`:

```
B_array = A_array.map {|item| if item.name == 'Josh'}
```

A_array:

```
[id:0,name:"Josh",email:"josh@josh@gmail.com"],
[id:1,name:"Scott",email:"scott@josh@gmail.com"],
[id:2,name:"Josh",email:"dan@josh@gmail.com"]
```

Desired output for `B_array`:

```
[id:0,name:"Josh",email:"josh@josh@gmail.com"],
[id:2,name:"Josh",email:"dan@josh@gmail.com"]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`.select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-select):

```
a = [{id:0,name:"Josh",email:"josh@josh@gmail.com"},
     id:1,name:"Scott",email:"scott@josh@gmail.com"}]
b = a.select { |i| i[:name] == 'Josh' }
```

[`.select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-select) will filter based on a condition you give it and return the array of elements that pass the test.